# CardView custom with header

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview

I'm trying to create a custom `CardView` like this :

[image]

But I'm not able to do the stuff on the top... how could I do this?

And to do the stuff inside the cardView is ok if I create a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and then put a `LinearLayout` horizontal and in weigh 0 put another `LinearLayout` vertical with 3 `TextViews` and in weigh 1 `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView`? Could you guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

see [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView); you can use:

- `setBackground(Drawable arg0)`
- `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable arg0)`
- `setBackgroundResource(int arg0)`

together with a `drawable` resource, which has that shape.

Comment: Can you put an example pleae of a shape?